# Jquery - fill input if user exist

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to fill a form if I find that the name and the firstname input by the user already exist in my database.

For the moment, I would like to check if the name and the firstname already exist in the database but my javascript program  doesn't work. It's seems that the part..." **"$.post("../modules/verifier_staff.php",{ nom: ..."**  is not correct.
Then I would like to fill my form with the data that my database give (array).

Can somenone help me to find my mistakes and to tell me how I can use the data i receive from database to fill my form?

```
$(document).ready(function(){   

    var form_nom = $("#staff_nom");
    var form_prenom = $("#staff_prenom");

    $(form_nom).change(function() {
        checkvariable();
    });
    $(form_prenom).change(function() {
        checkvariable();
    });


    function checkvariable(){
        if((form_nom.val().length >0)&&(form_prenom.val().length>0)){
            prenom_staff = form_prenom.val();
            nom_staff = form_nom.val();
            //alert(nom_staff);
            $.post("../modules/verifier_staff.php",{ nom: nom_staff, prenom: prenom_staff},
                function(data){
                if(data)
                {
                    alert('ok');
                }
                else alert('nok');
             });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you have the source for `../modules/verifier_staff.php`?

Comment: Are you sure the path is correct, any messages in the console or NET tab of the developers tools?

Answer (score 0):

```
var form_nom = $("#staff_nom");
var form_prenom = $("#staff_prenom");

$(form_nom).change(function() {
    checkvariable(form_nom,form_prenom);    //pass arguments into the function
});
$(form_prenom).change(function() {
    checkvariable(form_nom,form_prenom);
});

function checkvariable(form_nom,form_prenom){  //innclude argument in function definition
    //......
}
```

Comment: I tried but the result are the same - no answer. I don't think I need to send arguments in the function because I declare the variables at the begining of the program. Plus, this part of the program works well:      function checkvariable(){
        if((form_nom.val().length >0)&&(form_prenom.val().length>0)){
            prenom_staff = form_prenom.val();
            nom_staff = form_nom.val();
            alert(nom_staff); -> this part works even if I didn't send argument to the function. But thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

thank for your help. Yes I'm sure that the path is correct.
Here is my code from ../modules/verifier_staff.php

```
<?php
  include('../inc/settings.php');
  include('../inc/includes.php');

//$_POST['nom']='Doe';
//$_POST['prenom']='John';

$nom=$_POST['nom'];
$prenom=$_POST['prenom'];

 $Dbcon = new Db;
 $personne_manager = new PersonneManager($Dbcon->dbh);
 $personne = $personne_manager->get(array('conditions'=> array('nom' => strtolower($nom),'prenom' => strtolower($prenom))));

 if($personne)
 {
    $result = true;
 }
 else
 {
    $result = false;
 }

 return $result;

?>
```

this part works well (I tested it) so I think the problem come from my javascript code. I'm a newbie in javascript/jquery.